# Maximum likelihood for the Brownian Motion with drift

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, maximum-likelihood

Given the Brownian Motion with drift

$$
dX(t) = \mu dt + \sigma dW(t)
$$

It is well known that its distribution has the following form

$$
f_t(x) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt(2 \pi \sigma^2 t)} e^{-\frac{(x -\mu t)^2}{2 \sigma^2 t}} 
$$

So following examples online for the Normal distribution, I get the following formulas for the parameters of the BM distribution

$$
\mu = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i}{t_i}  \\
\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\mu t_i)^2
$$

Does this look correct? Please let me know if I need to show my work. Thanks

**Edit 2** - Let's start this over

Step 1 - Define the Likelihood function:

$$
\mathcal{L}(\mu, \sigma;x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} Pr(x_i|\mu, \sigma)= \left(2 \pi t_1\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \times \left(2 \pi t_2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \times ... \times \left(2 \pi t_n\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \left(\sigma^2 \right)^{-\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}e^{-\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \frac{(x_i -\mu t_i)^2}{t_i}}
$$

Step 2 - Take the log of the likelihood function

$$
\mathcal{l}(\mu, \sigma;x) = -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2 \pi t_1) -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2 \pi t_2) - ... -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2 \pi t_n) -\frac{n}{2} \ln(\sigma^2) -\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_i - \mu t_i)}{t_i} 
$$

So, before we take derivatives - I am not sure how to go from this

$$
-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2 \pi t_1) -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2 \pi t_2) - ... -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2 \pi t_n)
$$

to this for the first term

$$
- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln(2 \pi (t_i - t_{i-1}))
$$

Are we making any assumptions? The algebra does not work out for me.

Comment: Terribly phrased question. If you are asking for the MLE, please precise it and show your work.

Comment: @Did I added the work steps and I think the problem is that $t$s cannot be factored.

Comment: Actually, the correct log-likelihood is $$
\ell(\mu, \sigma;x) =  - \frac12\sum_i \ln ( 2 \pi (t_i-t_{i-1}))- \frac12\sum_i \ln (\sigma^2) - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2}  \sum_i\frac1{t_i-t_{i-1}}(x_i - \mu t_i)^2 $$
hence $\hat\mu$ solves $$
\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial\mu}(\hat\mu, \hat\sigma;x) =0$$ that is, $$\sum_i2t_i\frac1{t_i-t_{i-1}}(x_i - \hat\mu t_i)=0$$ that is, $$\hat\mu=\frac1T\sum_i\frac{t_ix_i}{t_i-t_{i-1}}$$ where $$T=\sum_i\frac{t_i^2}{t_i-t_{i-1}}$$ Can you proceed likewise to compute $\hat\sigma^2$?

Comment: @Did I will try once i understand the log likelihood you wrote. Thank you

Comment: @Did is there a chance - you can write the final answer for $\sigma$ so i can work backwards.

Comment: Sorry but what is preventing you to solve $$\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial\sigma}(\mu,\hat\sigma,x)=0$$ or, even better, $$\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial\sigma^2}(\mu,\hat\sigma,x)=0\ ?$$

Comment: @Did Can you please look at the math I added above. I have no idea how we end up with a difference $(t_i - t_{i-1})$.

Comment: Yes, your PDF is wrong, for example, the joint PDF of $(X(t),X(s))$ for $t<s$ is $$f_{X(t),X(s)}(x,y)=f_t(x)f_{s-t}(y-x)$$ Which, by the way, shows that I was too careless as well and that, actually, $$ \ell(\mu, \sigma;x) =  - \frac12\sum_i \ln ( 2 \pi (t_i-t_{i-1}))- \frac12\sum_i \ln (\sigma^2) - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2}  \sum_i\frac1{t_i-t_{i-1}}(x_i-x_{i-1} - \mu (t_i-t_{i-1})^2 $$